# How to ignore and initialize Missing key(s) in state_dict

Tags: python, pytorch

My saved state_dict does not contain all the layers that are in my model.
How can I ignore the Missing key(s) in state_dict error and initialize the remaining weights?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

This can be achieved by passing `strict=False` to `load_state_dict`.

```
load_state_dict(state_dict, strict=False)
```

[Documentation](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.Module.html?highlight=load_state_dict#torch.nn.Module.load_state_dict)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following snippet:

```
self.model.load_state_dict(dict([(n, p) for n, p in checkpoint['model'].items()]), strict=False)
```

where `checkpoint['model']` is the pre-trained model that you want to load into your model, and `self.model` is the model (inherits from `nn.Module`) with the associated blocks that match with the saved checkpoint.

Comment: If some keys from the model are missing in the save weights, this will still return a missing keys error. What I want to do is to load saved weights only for the keys that are in the state_dict.